# Scaled Shoenfeld Residuals

Tags: survival, residuals, cox-model, proportional-hazards

When constructing a multi-variable Cox model, is it necessary to check the proportional hazard assumption for each covariate individually by first fitting a univariable model and checking the Shoenfeld residuals before entering it into the final model? If I have checked the PH assumption for each covariate, is it still necessary to check the Shoenfeld residuals for the final multivariable model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more common to compare chi-squared statistics (and their p-values) based on scaled Schoenfeld residuals for each of the variables in a multi-variable model, not each of the univariate models.  Also, the p-value for the "overall" model based on the chi-squared statistic should not be significant (not less than 0.05).

Comment: I see. So is there any value in constructing univariate models before entering them into the overall model, or is it necessary to check for PH assumption at all for each of the covariates using, e.g. log-log plot, interaction with time, etc? Or should all these only be done at the end with the overall model? What about functional form for continuous variables, should that be checked using Martingale residuals individually before they are entered into the overall model? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's simply called model building strategies (MBS), for which you include in the multi-variable ("full") model any univariate p-value <0.25.  Recall, in Cox PH univariate models there's not a constant term, only the predictor itself, so you only need to focus on one p-value.   Whereas, during MBS for logistic regression or linear regression there's two coefficients in each univariate model.  For logistic and linear MBS, the p<0.25 criterion for MBS is based on the predictor, and not the constant term (y-intcp).

Comment: By the way, the evaluation of the proportional hazards assumption using scaled Schoenfeld residuals is based on the full model, composed of univariate predictor models for which p<0.25.   So the answer I provided is based on the full model after MBS.